# Universal way to convert object to other data types?

Tags: c#, .net

I have multiple lines where I expicitly say that I want to convert something to `string` or `bool` or `date` etc..

Is it possible to somehow encapsulate it within method where I pass object that I want to convert and also pass what I want to get in return?

## What I have now

```
foreach (var item in archive.Items)
{
    var newItem = new Item();
    newItem.Notes = Convert.ToString(item.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "notes").Value);
    newItem.IsPublic = Convert.ToBoolean(item.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "ispublic").Value);
}
```

## What I would like to have (pseudo)

```
foreach (var item in archive.Items)
{
    var newItem = new Item();
    newItem.Notes = GetValue("notes", string)
    newItem.IsPublic = GetValue("ispublic", bool)
}

// ...

public T GetValue(string key, T type)
{
    return object.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key).Value; // Convert this object to T and return?
}
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Do you actually need to convert the value or does it just need to be typecasted?  If `Value` returns an object you probably just want to cast it, not convert it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to write a generic wrapper around `Convert.ChangeType()`:

```
public T GetValue<T>(string key) {
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(..., typeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public T GetValue<T>(string key, T type)
{
    return Convert.ChangeType(object.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key).Value, typeof(T));
}
```